# Выбор среды разработки

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Хочу попробовать разрабатывать под андроид на Java, работал в intelliJ idea до этого, привык к ней, установил андроид студио и вопрос вот в чем: будет ли как-то отличаться структура и принцип написания кода в идее и в студио (например для одного и того же проекта)?

Comment: IDEA положена в основу Android Studio

Comment: Нет, базовый функционал весь тот же, андроид студия немного подрезана (это только на пользу) и немного удобнее.

Comment: Также `intelliJ idea` не всегда успевает за `Android Studio`. Например не давно был случай, когда AS поддерживала последний `android-gradle-plugin`, а Idea - нет. Засим используйте тот инструмент который предназначен для андроида напрямую. Тем паче, что там всё будет вам знакомо.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо всем за ответ!